# AWS SNS Deploy notification to slack return as json

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, slack-api

I have create a CICD pipeline to my EC2 machine and also configure cloudfront cache clear at the end. After cloudfront cache clear with lambda function it trigger SNS notification to send deploy success notification to my slack channel.

Right now everything works fine but the deploy success notification i received in my slack channel is in json format. I think its returning entire json source. I did try to setup publish message but it work only when I test lambda function manually..

My Lambda python 3.7 code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import urllib3
import json
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/web___hook__url"
    msg = {
        "channel": "#deploy-notifications", //my channel name
        "username": "WEBHOOK_USERNAME",  // do I need to change this WEBHOOK_USERNAME ? if yes with what ?
        "text": event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'],
        "icon_emoji": ""
    }
    
    encoded_msg = json.dumps(msg).encode('utf-8')
    resp = http.request('POST',url, body=encoded_msg)
    print({
        "message": event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'], 
        "status_code": resp.status, 
        "response": resp.data
    })
```

Do I need to change this `WEBHOOK_USERNAME` ? if yes with what ?

`"username": "WEBHOOK_USERNAME",`

After this lambda function is triggered by clearing cloudfront Invalidating cache I received this json in my slack channel.

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "timestamp": "2022-08-31T14:23:20.379Z",
    "requestContext": {
        "requestId": "******-88d6-4fe8-876b-*****",
        "functionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:****:function:Clear_cloudfront_******_ssr:$LATEST",
        "condition": "Success",
        "approximateInvokeCount": 1
    },
    "requestPayload": {
        "Records": [{
            "EventSource": "aws:sns",
            "EventVersion": "1.0",
            "EventSubscriptionArn": "***************-Deploy-Success:***************",
            "Sns": {
                "Type": "Notification",
                "MessageId": "******-af7d-5ca3-b95b-*********",
                "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:***********:*****-Deploy-Success",
                "Subject": "SUCCEEDED: AWS CodeDeploy d-**** in us-east-1 to *******-code-deploy",
                "Message": "{\"region\":\"us-east-1\",\"accountId\":\"******\",\"eventTriggerName\":\"******DeploySuccess\",\"applicationName\":\"*****-code-deploy\",\"deploymentId\":\"d-*****\",\"deploymentGroupName\":\"ec2-code-deploy-dg\",\"createTime\":\"Wed Aug 31 14:23:05 UTC 2022\",\"completeTime\":\"Wed Aug 31 14:23:17 UTC 2022\",\"deploymentOverview\":\"{\\\"Succeeded\\\":1,\\\"Failed\\\":0,\\\"Skipped\\\":0,\\\"InProgress\\\":0,\\\"Pending\\\":0}\",\"status\":\"SUCCEEDED\"}",
                "Timestamp": "2022-08-31T14:23:18.215Z",
                "SignatureVersion": "1",
                "Signature": "*********/***+**/************/******==",
                "SigningCertUrl": "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-******.pem",
                "UnsubscribeUrl": "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:*****:****-Deploy-Success:****-*****-****",
                "MessageAttributes": {}
            }
        }]
    },
    "responseContext": {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "executedVersion": "$LATEST"
    },
    "responsePayload": null
}
```

[image]

How can I return plain message. Where it says only "Code deployment success."

Comment: Why dont you use aws chatbot service

Comment: I will definitely try aws chatbot for this atleast. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `"text"` field to be whatever message you'd like.

```py
[...]
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/web___hook__url"
    msg = {
        "channel": "#deploy-notifications", //my channel name
        "username": "WEBHOOK_USERNAME",  // do I need to change this WEBHOOK_USERNAME ? if yes with what ?
        "text": ":white_check_mark: Code deployment success.",
        "icon_emoji": ""
    }
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks it did work. but can you explain why my `vent['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']`  is also returning json ?

Comment: Because essentially the event that occurs is in JSON and the SNS topic will embed it in the `event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']` part of the full SNS event.